# How to add calculated column in bigquery data table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, calculated-columns

I am using the below code:

```
ALTER TABLE `trim-opus-308402.Covid_Dataset_SQL_Practice_24May21.Percentage vaccine`
ADD COLUMN Vaccine_Coverage numeric AS  ((Rolling_vaccination / population)*100)
```

I am getting error message:

> ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN does not support generated columns yet at
> [2:12]

Answer (score 2):

You can add an empty column to your schema using this syntax, but I don't think you can fill it in the same operation. You might consider a two step approach:

```
ALTER TABLE `trim-opus-308402.Covid_Dataset_SQL_Practice_24May21.Percentage vaccine`
ADD COLUMN Vaccine_Coverage NUMERIC;

UPDATE `trim-opus-308402.Covid_Dataset_SQL_Practice_24May21.Percentage vaccine`
SET Vaccine_Coverage = (Rolling_vaccination / population)*100
WHERE TRUE;
```